# No hay validacion en los archivos que subo en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

En la validación de creación de una entrada de post uso este request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PostStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'name'        => 'required',
        'slug'        => 'required|unique:posts,slug',
        'user_id'     => 'required|integer',
        'category_id' => 'required|integer',
        'tags'        => 'required|array',
        'body'        => 'required',
        'status'      => 'required|in:DRAFT,PUBLISHED',
    ];

    if($this->get('file'))
        $rules = array_merge($rules, ['file' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png']);

    if($this->get('file2'))
        $rules = array_merge($rules, ['file2' => 'mimes:pdf|max:2048']);

    return $rules;
}
}
```

La validación cuando subo un archivo, que serian file para imágenes y file2 para pdfs no funciona, me deja subir básicamente cualquier tipo de archivos sin validar de que tipo son. Esos campos son nullable, por eso el if en ambos.
El resto de las validaciones funciona perfectamente.

**Edit1:** La version de Laravel que uso es la 5.5

Adjunto el formulario que utilizo tanto para crear como para editar los posts:

```
{{ Form::hidden('user_id', auth()->user()->id) }}

<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('category_id', 'Categorias') }}
{{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre de la etiqueta') }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'name']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('slug', 'URL amigable') }}
{{ Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'slug']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('file', 'Imagen') }}
{{ Form::file('file') }}
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('file2', 'Notas') }}
{{ Form::file('file2') }}   
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('status', 'Estado') }}
<label >
    {{ Form::radio('status', 'PUBLISHED') }} Publicado
</label>
<label >
    {{ Form::radio('status', 'DRAFT') }} Borrador
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('tags', 'Etiquetas') }}
<div>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
    <label>
        {{ Form::checkbox('tags[]', $tag->id) }} {{ $tag->name }}
    </label>
    @endforeach
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('excerpt', 'Extracto') }}
{{ Form::textarea('excerpt', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '2']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('body', 'Descripcion') }}
{{ Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
</div>

@section('scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.min.js') }}">
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/stringToSlug/jquery.stringToSlug.js') }}">
</script>
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name, #slug").stringToSlug({
        callback: function(text){
            $('#slug').val(text);
        }
    });
});

CKEDITOR.config.height = 400;
CKEDITOR.config.width  = 'auto';

CKEDITOR.replace('body');
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Sería bueno ver el código de la vista y conocer la versión exacta de Laravel que utilizas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre la documentación indica que si son imágenes, puedes utilizar el filtro `image`, para que el filtro mimetypes funcione, debes capturar el tipo de documento y el formato, ejemplo;

```
image/jpeg
image/png
image/bmp
image/gif
application/pdf
```

y deberías utilizar la función `hasFile` de Request, que es la que verifica si se subió un archivo, `get` verifica sobre los parámetros que van en la url,
aplicado a tu filtro seria

```
if($this->hasFile('file'))
    $rules = array_merge($rules, ['file' => 'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp,image/gif']);

if($this->hasFile('file2'))
    $rules = array_merge($rules, ['file2' => 'mimetypes:application/pdf|max:2048']);

return $rules;
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente de esta forma, muy agradecido.